# Как заставить блок перемещаться на плоскости при помощи "стрелок" на клавиатуре?

Tags: javascript

На странице расположен квадрат, надо написать скрипт JS, чтобы при каждом нажатии на "стрелки" вправо-влево-вверх-вниз на клавиатуре, квадрат перемещался на 5 пикселей в соответствующую сторону.

```js
'use strict'                
let box5Move = document.querySelector('.box5');
box5Move.style.top = 100;
box5Move.style.left = 100;
window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {            
    if (e.keyCode === '40') box5Move.style.top = parseInt(box5Move.style.top) + 5 + 'px';
    else if (e.keyCode === '38') box5Move.style.top = parseInt(box5Move.style.top) - 5 + 'px';            
    else if (e.keyCode === '37') box5Move.style.left = parseInt(box5Move.style.left) - 5 + 'px';
    else if(e.keyCode === '39') box5Move.style.left = parseInt(box5Move.style.left) + 5 + 'px';
})
```

```css
.boxWide {
    position: relative;
    margin: 5px 10x;
}    
.box5 {
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;                
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    border-radius: 3px;  
    position: absolute;
    background: #d37116;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxWide">                
    <div id="divBox5" class="box5"></div>
</div>
<!--    keyCode     key
        40          ArrowDown 
        39          ArrowRight
        37          ArrowLeft
        40          ArrowDown
        38          ArrowUp -->
```

Comment: `box5Move.style` относится к инлайн-стилям

Comment: у вас изначально `box5Move.style.top` не определен, поэтому `parseInt(box5Move.style.top)` дает `NaN`

Comment: аааа, вы их определяете, но не правильно. `box5Move.style.top = 100;` так нельзя

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Извращение, но прикольное изврашение))

```js
'use strict'
let box5Move = document.querySelector('.box5');
let pos = {top: 100, left: 100}
box5Move.style.top = pos.top + 'px';
box5Move.style.left = pos.left + 'px';

let obj = {
  '40': ['top', 5], 
  '38': ['top', -5], 
  '39': ['left', 5], 
  '37': ['left', -5],
}

addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  let key = obj[e.keyCode];
  if( key ){ // key[0] == 'top' или 'left'
    pos[ key[0] ] = pos[ key[0] ] + key[1];
    box5Move.style[ key[0] ] = pos[ key[0] ] + 'px';
  }
});
```

```css
.boxWide {
  position: relative;
  margin: 5px 10x;
}

.box5 {
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #d37116;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxWide">
  <div id="divBox5" class="box5"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Извините, но первое решение для меня понятно. Думаю, можно существенно оптимизировать. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

```js
const box5Move = document.querySelector('.box5');

document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  // float вернет нормальное значение у 100px, например.
  let lastTopCoords = parseFloat(box5Move.style.top);
  let lastLeftCoords = parseFloat(box5Move.style.left);

  // У вас изначально координаты в стилях прописаны. Поэтому style ничего не вернет.
  // Либо использовать getComputedStyles, либо так :)
  if (isNaN(lastTopCoords)) lastTopCoords = 100;
  if (isNaN(lastLeftCoords)) lastLeftCoords = 100;

  // Со switch красивее.
  switch(e.keyCode) {
    // e.keyCode - число, а не строка.
    case 40: {
      box5Move.style.top = `${lastTopCoords + 5}px`;
      break;
    }
    case 38: {
      box5Move.style.top = `${lastTopCoords - 5}px`;
      break;
    }
    case 37: {
      box5Move.style.left = `${lastLeftCoords - 5}px`;
      break;
    }
    case 39: {
      box5Move.style.left = `${lastLeftCoords + 5}px`;
      break;
    }
    default: break;
  }
});
```

```css
.boxWide {
    position: relative;
    margin: 5px 10x;
}    
.box5 {
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;                
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    border-radius: 3px;  
    position: absolute;
    background: #d37116;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxWide">                
    <div id="divBox5" class="box5"></div>
</div>
<!--    keyCode     key
        40          ArrowDown 
        39          ArrowRight
        37          ArrowLeft
        40          ArrowDown
        38          ArrowUp -->
```